# @RunWith annotation not found in Android studio

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, androidx

I've and android studio project which is having following test related dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

// Core library
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'

// AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'

// Assertions
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

// Espresso dependencies
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.1.1'

// The following Espresso dependency can be either "implementation"
// or "androidTestImplementation", depending on whether you want the
// dependency to appear on your APK's compile classpath or the test APK
// classpath.
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.1'
```

Still Android studio fails to import @RunWith annotation. I had the same issue while using API 28 design library of andoridx. I believe androidx still sucks, even when it's asked to developer to use androidx libraries!!

> My gradle tool version is '3.3.2' and android studio stable version is
>   3.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you were in the correct build variant? I had the same issue and switching to the `debug` build variant let me add the imports correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies to your `build.gradle` of app module:

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

And make sure you are in the **androidTest package** and using the **debug** Build Variant as well